# Cannot get anything to return via SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (jobs) that I am trying to query specific jobs in a time range.  The hard part that I am hitting is that the job stream runs over the date change (00:00).  So when I am putting in the date I want to see the job stream for, and I enter (for example) 2014-02-11, the logic searches for the job name that was started on the day before what was entered (because the job stream runs over the date change), and then get's all the jobs that run in between there and the end job (on the actual date that was entered in).  I have written this query:

```
SELECT job_name, job_start_time, job_end_time 
FROM job WHERE (job_start_time LIKE '2014-02-10%' AND job_name = 'start')
AND (job_end_time LIKE '2014-02-11%' AND job_name = 'end')
ORDER BY job_end_time ASC;
```

I can do this programatically in java and parse out the extra non-job stream related jobs, but I'd rather hit the database once and just have the data there that is needed.  I thought about trying an inner select, but from everything that I have read, #1, they can be costly and #2 are usually more expensive than a single select.

The above query is returning 0 results and I'm at a loss of what I did wrong.

Comment: It would help if you could include your schema and some sample data in a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `like` for anything but strings.  So, first try this version:

```
SELECT job_name, job_start_time, job_end_time 
FROM job
WHERE (date(job_start_time) = date('2014-02-10') AND job_name = 'start') or
      (date(job_end_time) = date('2014-02-11') AND job_name = 'end')
ORDER BY job_end_time ASC;
```

I also changed the logic to `or`, because the `job_name` cannot be both `start` and `end` in the same record.

Comment: Surely `date('2014-02-10')` is the same as `'2014-02-10'`?  And `date(job_start_time)` etc isn't sargable, so surely it'd be better to do something like `job_start_time >= '2014-02-10' AND job_start_time < '2014-02-11'`?

Comment: @Gordon, this returns me the start and end jobs which is a great start.  I'm messing around with the query to try and get all the jobs that fall between that date range.

Comment: @ResourceReaper . . . If you continue to have problems, ask *another* question.  Getting the records in-between is quite different.  And, add sample data and desired results to the new question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry!  I'll ask a secondary question, your solution got me close.  I'll fiddle with it for a while and see what I can come up with before just throwing in the towel.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The glaring issue is that you have `job_name = 'start' AND job_name = 'end'`, just separated by a few other terms. `job_name` can never be two things at once, so you'll always get nothing back.